# Where's the iNXTG app for programming NXT from iPad?

Tags: nxt, programming, software, ios

I'm trying to find the old iNXTG to program NXT bricks via iPad but it is no longer available in the Apple Store. Does anyone know if there exists an archive for programs like that?

The problem is that the new LEGO programmer for EV3 does not recognize the NXT brick with Bluetooth or a USB connection. We have no laptops in school, just iPads and Chromebooks.

Does anyone know of an NXTG version that would run on iPads or Chromebooks?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no good solution for controlling NXT’s from an iPad. There are plenty of *Android* apps to control them manually, but you’re best bet on iOS is to write something on your own. LEGO does provide a Bluetooth Developer Kit with the info so it is possible.